# How to get storage details of Google Photos using API - C#

Tags: c#, google-photos, google-photos-api

We have been using Picasa Web Albums Data API to perform all required features such as upload photos, GetAlbums list, get album's photos, storage details (how much used).

Now we are migrating to new Google Photos API and we are succeeded in authentication, creation of albums as of now.

We are facing hard time to get storage details using new Google Photos API. Previously we were using "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default?access_token=" to get the details.

Since we are not including Picasa scopes while authentication we need to get those things using Photos API only.

We have tried hard to get few pointers online but no luck.

Can anyone please direct me how to proceed so that we can get storage details, upload photos/videos etc.

One more quick query please: When we upload photos to Google Photos it will count against daily quota provided by Google Photos (10000/per day/per project)?

Thanks in advance.